# unable to set Overlays in List items using css

Tags: css

i am working on this grid gallery where List items are set to width 20% so that they can be like 5 in one row using float left.
Now i am using a div with class overlay so that hen someone hovers over Li the overlayis shown.
the problem is 
when i give overlay 100% width and height 100% it covers the whole screen and not just that Li.
here is my HTML code

```
   <ul id="thumbsList">
    <li>
        <div class="overlay">Hello</div>
    </li>
    <li><div class="overlay">Hello2</div></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my Css

```
#thumbsList {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#thumbsList li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.overlay {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Please help me fix the problem.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add position: relative to the li item, the absolute positioning in the overlay wil take this as reference.

```
#thumbsList li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

Also you need to add a display: none to the overlay and a hover on li that change the display: none to display: block on the overlay, like this:

```
#thumbsList li:hover .overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HPJ8v/